# Clear Task and New Task Flags on Launching Activity From Deeplink

Tags: android, android-activity, launch, deeplink

I need my deep link activity is launched with flags  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK on launching from deeplinks.

The idea is to clear all existing activities and start a new one.

Is this possible with android:lauchMode parameter?

Comment: have you tried Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: The activity is not starting from another activity. Its starting on clicking deep links. So, I need something to set on manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```